# MySQL is so slow on Amazon EC2 m1.large

Tags: mysql

I'm migration my .NET/MSSQL to RoR/MySQL/EC2/Ubuntu platform. After I transferred all my existing data into MySQL, I found the MySQL querying speed is incredibily slow, even for a super-basic query , like querying a `select count(*) from countries`, it's just a country table, only contains around 200 records, but it takes 0.124ms for the query. It's obviously not normal.

I'm a newbie to MySQL, can anyone tell me what would be the possible problem? Or any initial optimization button I should turn on after installing MySQL?

Comment: Why do you believe that 124μs (microseconds), or 1/8000th of a second, is a high value to parse and execute that query? What were you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

`count(*)` operation cannot really be optimized since it has to either do a full table scan (`O(n)`), or read the cached table count (`O(1)`) depending on the database engine you are using. Either ways, your query should not be that slow. You might want to get in touch with AWS support. It's possible the box is being choked by some other process running on it.